# Acrescentar item vazio ao final da ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Eu tenho um `FloatingActionButton` no canto inferior direito da minha tela e, quando chega ao final da `ListView`, ele fica em cima de um botão. Gostaria de acrescentar um item vazio ao final da `ListView` para que quando chegasse ao final da lista isso não acontecesse.

Quero fazer igual tem no Gmail:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O espaço em branco aparece só quando chega no último item. Estou usando adaptador para minha ListView:

```
public class AdaptadorProdutosSemelhantes extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] nomeprod,estabelecimentoprod,precoprod;
    int[] imgprod;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public AdaptadorProdutosSemelhantes(int[] imgprod, String[] nomeprod, String[] estabelecimentoprod, String[] precoprod, Context context) {
        this.nomeprod = nomeprod;
        this.estabelecimentoprod = estabelecimentoprod;
        this.precoprod = precoprod;
        this.context = context;
        this.imgprod = imgprod;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nomeprod.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder{
        ImageView imgproduto;
        TextView nomeproduto,precoproduto,estabelecimentoproduto;
        Button vertodas;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder h = new Holder();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_produtos_semelhantes,null);
        h.imgproduto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgprodsemelhante);
        h.nomeproduto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nomeprodsemelhante);
        h.precoproduto= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precoprodsemelhante);
        h.estabelecimentoproduto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.infosupprodsemelhante);
        h.vertodas = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.vertodasofertas);
        h.ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarprodsemelhante);
        h.imgproduto.setImageResource(imgprod[position]);
        h.nomeproduto.setText(nomeprod[position]);
        h.precoproduto.setText(precoprod[position]);
        h.estabelecimentoproduto.setText(estabelecimentoprod[position]);

        h.vertodas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: E se você desse um padding bottom na sua lista? Não resolveria??

Comment: Você pode adicionar um item vazio na hora em que preenche seu String[] na Activity que você chama seu adapter. Para adicionar é só você verificar o tamanho de seu vetor e acrescentar +1. Ai tem que observar se seu item tem tamanho variável. Se for tamanho variável, você teria que setar um tamanho fixo para que o botão float não fique por cima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver seu problema, existem várias possibilidades. Às vezes o botão de ação não é vital o suficiente para que ele precisa ser visto o tempo todo. Em alguns casos, escondendo-o enquanto a rolagem para baixo pode fazer bastante sentido.

Diretrizes atualizadas do Google mostram uma versão - [Floating action button](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) - para animar o botão entrando e saindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já, também para seu caso, você pode usar [ListView#addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) para adicionar uma View de exibição na parte inferior do ListView.

Voê pode tentar assim criando uma `classe Viewtypes`:

```
private class Viewtypes{
        public static final int Header = 1;
        public static final int Normal = 2;
        public static final int Footer = 3;
}
```

Em seguida no seu `Adapter`:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(items.get(position).isHeader)
        return Viewtypes.Header;
    else if(items.get(position).isFooter)
        return Viewtypes.Footer;
    else
        return Viewtypes.Normal;

}
```

GetView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;

    switch (position)
    {
        case Viewtypes.Normal:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, parent, false);
            break;
        case Viewtypes.Header:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
            break;
        case Viewtypes.Footer:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer, parent, false);
            break;
        default:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, parent, false);
            break;
    }
    return new ViewHolder (rowView);
}
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Deu certo! Usei a ideia do rodapé :)